# Java : assign a value in single row

Tags: java

Im learning java from basics. One of the book they claimed 
`int h = f = 10;` will work but in real time its not working. Please explain.

My code:

```
int h = f = 10;
```

Why it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
int h, f;
h = f = 10;
```

but keep in mind, this will only work with immutable objects, like `Integer` or `String`. You cannot use the same for an object of a class because they would be pointing on the same instance and if you modify one, you'll modify the others !

Answer (score 0):

We have to declare h and f first.

```
int a, b, c, d;

a= b = c = d = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `f` is not declared yet. This will work:

```
int f, h;
h = f = 10;
```